# SQL - Count of a column until specific result

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table containing info on call attempts on contacts. The relevant fields are below:

```
Contact     Date        Result
John Smith  1/8/2013    VM
John Smith  1/9/2013    VM
John Smith  1/10/2013   Busy Signal
John Smith  1/11/2013   Hang Up                   <--- Connect
Jane Smith  1/8/2013    VM
Jane Smith  1/9/2013    Scheduled Call Back       <--- Connect
Jane Smith  1/10/2013   VM
John Doe    1/8/2013    Not Interested            <--- Connect
Jane Doe    1/8/2013    Busy Signal
Jane Doe    1/9/2013    Busy Signal
Jane Doe    1/10/2013   Busy Signal
```

I'm trying to get a count of the number of attempts until connect by contact (and not any attempts after the first connect), or the number of attempts so far if no connect has been made, and I'm having trouble. The results that would signify a connect in this case would be Hang Up, Scheduled Call Back and Not Interested.

What I am trying to get would look like:

```
Contact       Attempts
John Smith    4
Jane Smith    2
John Doe      1
Jane Doe      3
```

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What values of `Result` indicate a successful connection?

Comment: Hang Up, Scheduled Call Back and Not Interested are the successful connections

Comment: @brianchrystal what database are you using?

Comment: Wouldn't `John Doe` be mad if you called his wife after he said he wasn't interested?

Comment: @brianchrystal I am confused why you accepted an answer that will not work in MySQL. MySQL does not have a `row_number()` function. What database are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet I was testing it on sql fiddle, by adding extra entries to see if the outcome was what I expected, and it was, so I thought that was the solution. I did not realize until later last night that it was for MS SQL and not MySQL, and found out this morning that the row_number() does not work with MySQL. The answer has been unaccepted.

Comment: @brianchrystal Ah, ok, I was confused. Thanks for clarifying that. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Contact, COUNT(*) Attempts
FROM Contacts 
WHERE Result NOT IN ('Hang Up','Scheduled Call Back','Not Interested')
GROUP BY Contact
```

--EDIT

Didn't realize OP's request.  And couldn't finish this before he accepted another answer...

Good luck.

Comment: Look at closer. OP notice expected result where mode than one of same contact.

Comment: For John Doe, wouldn't that return 0? And if Jane Doe had another VM, it would return 3?

Comment: @brianchrystal -- Sorry for the confusion -- just updated my answer.  Good luck.

Comment: @brianchrystal -- saw bugs in my testing and removed the answer -- glad you got what you needed.  Good luck.

Comment: @sgeddes I added in a few extra entries to check and it counted them (which it shouldn't). Kaf's solution worked. However I want to thank you for looking at the issue, and a huge thank you for the introduction to sql fiddle. I love it!

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    t.Contact, COUNT(*) AS Attempts
FROM 
    tableX AS t
  JOIN 
          ( SELECT DISTINCT contact
            FROM tableX
          ) AS d
      LEFT JOIN
          ( SELECT contact, 
                   MIN(date) AS date 
            FROM tableX
            WHERE result IN ('Hang Up', 'Scheduled Call Back', 'Not Interested')
            GROUP BY contact
          ) AS g
        ON d.contact = g.contact
    ON  t.contact = d.contact
    AND t.date <= COALESCE(g.date, '9999-12-31')
GROUP BY
    t.contact ;
```